# Put first element of tikz above the axis to make a "L" shaped arrow

Tags: tikz-matrix, flow-charts

I'd like to position the first element of my chart just above the x axis to make the first line like a "L" shape.
Here is what I have now:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning, fit, arrows}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,
        mymatrix/.style={
            matrix of nodes,
            nodes={typetag},
            row sep=1em,
            align=center
            },
        mycontainer/.style={draw=gray, inner sep=1ex},
        typetag/.style={draw=gray, inner sep=1ex, anchor=base,fill=green!50},
        title/.style={draw=none, color=gray, inner sep=0pt,fill=blue!10}
        ]

        \matrix[mymatrix,fill=blue!10] (ext) at (0,0) {
            |[title]|Externalisation? \\[.7em]
        };

        \matrix[mymatrix,fill=blue!10,right=45pt of ext] (source) {
            |[title]|Donnée source \\
            Chercher \\
            Transférer \\
            Stocker \\
        };
        \draw[->] (ext.south) |- node [above] {choix} node [below] {effectué} ++(1.5,0) |- (source.west) ;
        \matrix[mymatrix,fill=blue!10,right=75pt of source, nodes in empty cells,
    row 3/.style = {nodes={draw=none,fill=blue!10}}] (trans) {
            |[title]|Transformation \\
            Spécification \\
            \\
            Développement \\
        };
        \path[<->]
            (trans-2-1) edge node [midway,align=center] {enrichissement \\ mutuel} (trans-4-1);

        \draw[->] (source.east) -- node [above] {donnée source} node [below] {récupérée} ++(2.5,0) -- (trans.west);
        \matrix[mymatrix,fill=blue!10,right=75pt of trans] (int) {
            |[title]|Intégration \\
            Tests \\
            Bascule \\
        };

        \draw[double,<->] (trans.east) -- node [above] {enrichissement} node [below] {mutuel} ++(2.5,0) -- (int.west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the picture:
[image: chart]

You see that the first arrow is ugly...
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you mean by "L" shape. Do you want the "Externalisation?" block to be above left of all the others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.sx!

To get the accents and the typography right (e.g. a space before the `?`), use:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
```

Be careful, you have several places where you left a space before `\\`. LaTeX sees this space, and adds an extra space inside the node (this is why the text is not exactly centered, you can see it in the `Externalisation ?<space>` node for example. I removed the extra spaces that I saw in the code below.

To place the second matrix below right of the second one, use

```
        \matrix[mymatrix,fill=blue!10,below right=45pt of ext] (source) {
```

You can change the x and y distances independently as follows (the dimensions here are 5pt on the y axis and 45pt on the x axis):

```
        \matrix[mymatrix,fill=blue!10,below right=5pt and 45pt of ext] (source) {
```

Note that the distance is measured from edge to edge (or in this shape from corner to corner). If you want to measure the y position of the first matrix relative to the position where the arrow arrives in the second matrix, use `anchor=west` so that the second matrix hangs at the desired position from its west node (I use `1.5\baselineskip` to have a 1.5× interline instead of messing with `pt` by trial-and-error):

```
        \matrix[mymatrix,fill=blue!10,below right=1.5\baselineskip and 45pt of ext, anchor=west] (source) {
```

I used a dirty hack to place the text correctly. The `chx` is above the corner, to the right, and I place an `eff` node that is at the wrong place horizontally (but make it phantom so that it does not appear in the result). Then, I use `(chx |- eff)` to use the x of (the center of) `chx`, and the y of `eff` (since `eff` and the actual `effectué` nodes have the same height, they are aligned as expected, but note that by default it will use the `.west` anchor on `eff` and the `.center` anchor on `effectué`).

```
        \draw[->] (ext.south) |- node (chx) [above right] {choix} node (eff) [below right] {\phantom{effectué}} (source.west) ;
        \node at (chx |- eff) {effectué};
```

I find this nice (with the `choix` in the corner, and the `effectué` hanging slightly below), but if you wanted to have the left edge of `effectué` just below the corner, you could swap the `phantom` and the nodes on either side of the `|-`, as follows (then the `chx` is phantom, and the real `choix` is placed relative to `chx`'s y and `eff`'s y):

```
        \draw[->] (ext.south) |- node (chx) [above right] {\phantom{choix}} node (eff) [below right] {effectué} (source.west) ;
        \node at (eff |- chx) {choix};
```

The full source:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning, fit, arrows}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,
        mymatrix/.style={
            matrix of nodes,
            nodes={typetag},
            row sep=1em,
            align=center
            },
        mycontainer/.style={draw=gray, inner sep=1ex},
        typetag/.style={draw=gray, inner sep=1ex, anchor=base,fill=green!50},
        title/.style={draw=none, color=gray, inner sep=0pt,fill=blue!10}
        ]

        \matrix[mymatrix,fill=blue!10] (ext) at (0,0) {
            |[title]|Externalisation?\\[.7em]
        };

        \matrix[mymatrix,fill=blue!10,below right=1.5\baselineskip and 45pt of ext, anchor=west] (source) {
            |[title]|Donnée source\\
            Chercher\\
            Transférer\\
            Stocker\\
        };
        \draw[->] (ext.south) |- node (chx) [above right] {choix} node (eff) [below right] {\phantom{effectué}} (source.west) ;
        \node at (chx |- eff) {effectué};
        \matrix[mymatrix,fill=blue!10,right=75pt of source, nodes in empty cells,
    row 3/.style = {nodes={draw=none,fill=blue!10}}] (trans) {
            |[title]|Transformation\\
            Spécification\\
            \\
            Développement\\
        };
        \path[<->]
            (trans-2-1) edge node [midway,align=center] {enrichissement \\ mutuel} (trans-4-1);

        \draw[->] (source.east) -- node [above] {donnée source} node [below] {récupérée} ++(2.5,0) -- (trans.west);
        \matrix[mymatrix,fill=blue!10,right=75pt of trans] (int) {
            |[title]|Intégration\\
            Tests\\
            Bascule\\
        };

        \draw[double,<->] (trans.east) -- node [above] {enrichissement} node [below] {mutuel} ++(2.5,0) -- (int.west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Merci Georges.
I changed it a bit to make it closer: `below right=0pt and 25pt of ext`

Comment: @djcaesar9114 I noticed that there were some extra spaces in your code (before `\\`), which are small but visible. I finished adding some more explanations, and gave a slightly better way to position the second matrix (below right=1.5\baselineskip and 45pt of ext, anchor=west). Bon courage! :)